# Flutter cant save to android application directory

Tags: android, flutter, file, dart, directory

I have scoured the internet and am doing what everyone is saying to do but for some reason I can not save a file image or otherwise into the applications folder.

I have this method to get the applications directory...

```
Future<Directory> get _localAppPath async {
    Directory? directory;

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      Utilities.logInfo('Local Android App Path is: ${directory.path}');
    } else {
      // if IOS Device
      directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      Utilities.logInfo('Local IOS App Path is: $directory');
    }
    return directory;
  }
```

and I use it in my save method like so...

```
  Future<void> saveProfileImageLocally(File _file) async {
    try {
      final appDirPath = await _localAppPath;
      //Utilities.logWarning('New path is: ${appDirPath.path}');
      final fileExt = extension(_file.path);

      // Check is directory exists

      Utilities.logWarning('FilePath: ${_file.path}');
      File newFile = await _file.rename('${appDirPath.path}/images/profileImage$fileExt');
      Utilities.logWarning('New path is: ${newFile.path}');
      Storage.saveValue('profileImage', newFile.path);
    } catch (e) {
      Utilities.logError(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

I check permissions on every app launch so I know I have permissions
but no matter what I keep getting this error that there is no such file or directory...
I was trying to do use the copy function until I read another stackoverflow post.

```
FileSystemException: Cannot rename file to '/data/user/0/ca.company.example/app_flutter/images/profileImage.jpg', path = '/data/user/0/ca.company/example/cache/CAP370489784397780451.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

This should be a simple one line process from all the resources I keep reading online and tutorials and and and... So I'm pretty confused to what step I'm missing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `await _file.copy()` rather than `rename()`?

Comment: yes i was doing most my attempting with copy at first, I only recently seen a forum of someone using rename as its supposed to create if not there from my understanding

Answer (score 1):

So after some extensive googling and trial and errors I finally made a few smaller methods to Get everything working.

First I create a directory which checkes if it already exists or not and tack on whatever folder name I'm trying to save in.

```
  // Checked and working
  Future<String> createFolderInAppDocDir(String folderName) async {
    //Get this App Document Directory

    final Directory _appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    //App Document Directory + folder name
    final Directory _appDocDirFolder = Directory('${_appDocDir.path}/$folderName');

    final Directory _appDocDirNewFolder = await _appDocDirFolder.create(recursive: true);
    return _appDocDirNewFolder.path;
  }
```

Then I made another method to implement the saving to the location based on what type of file im saving...

```
  Future<File?> saveFileLocally(String type, File _file) async {
    File tmp;
    try {
      // Create or get Folder location
      final appDir = await createFolderInAppDocDir(type);

      // Get File Extension
      String fileExt = extension(_file.path);

      // Copy file to new location
      tmp = await _file.copy('$appDir/${Timestamp.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}$fileExt');

      // Delete cached file
      final bool tmpExists = await tmp.exists();
      if (tmpExists) _file.delete();

      //Utilities.logWarning('New path is: ${tmp.path}');
      return tmp;
    } catch (e) {
      Utilities.logError('Error: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

The Utilities.logError is just a debug statement color codes so I can find them easier. Now it works like a charm for anything I need to save.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the file I think. just look at the below code

```
//File created.
    File tmpFile = File(imageFile.path);

    final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
//filename - returns last part after the separator - path package.
    final fileName = basename(imageFile.path);
//copy the file to the specified directory and return File instance.
    tmpFile = await tmpFile.copy('${appDirPath.path}/images/profileImage$fileExt');
```

Comment: Thank for the suggestion thats pretty much what my code does now. Although in hopes that I am doing something silly and wrong I attempted this and sure enough I got the same error back. cannot copy file to (OS: Error: no such file or directory, errno = 2

Comment: Either file does not exist or the directory you are trying to access. Use device file explorer in AS and check

Comment: Without more code or error stack we can't help you